# How can I mutate the most recent date compared to a reference date by ID using Tidyverse?

Tags: r

I am looking for a solution in the Tidyverse to accomplish the following goal. I want to select the most recent date for each given date ("appointment_date") by ID ("client_number").

Data input:

| Client_number | Appointment_date |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 2021-06-03 |
| 1 | 2021-07-01 |
| 1 | 2021-08-26 |
| 2 | 2019-08-01 |
| 2 | 2019-08-15 |
| 2 | 2019-09-02 |

Desired output:

| Client_number | Appointment_date | Last_appointment |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2021-06-03 | NA |
| 1 | 2021-07-01 | 2021-06-03 |
| 1 | 2021-08-26 | 2021-07-01 |
| 2 | 2019-08-01 | NA |
| 2 | 2019-08-15 | 2019-08-01 |
| 2 | 2019-09-02 | 2019-08-15 |

Answer (score 0):

We group by Client_number and then take the `lag`

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>%
    group_by(Client_number) %>%
    mutate(Last_appointment = lag(Appointment_date)) %>%
    ungroup
```